# Phoenix not returning any rows

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have a table in hbase. I created it with phoenix

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table ...
```

Then I populate it with spark (I use hortonworks shc-core connector):

```
df.write().options(options).format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase").save();
```

In hbase shell mode, I can see that my table in not empty:

```
scan "my_table", {LIMIT=>1}
 55f8477005f6f8.71923246\x00\x00\x00\x00Zd{y    column=cf1:id2, timestamp=1516703969207, value=...
```

But why I a run a query in the phoenix consol, I get not rows:

```
SELECT * FROM 'my_table' LIMIT 10 ;
No rows selected (4.033 seconds)
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase" try using "org.apache.phoenix.spark" as suggested by Phoenix official website [here](https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html) for saving DataFrame in phoenix table.

Comment: So your advice is to use phoenix everywhere, including in my spark job?